# Bugsnag error when running artisan command

Tags: laravel, bugsnag

I got this error when trying to run my `php artisan migrate` on my production server...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Bugsnag Error: Invalid API key' in /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Bugsnag/Client.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel/src/Bugsnag/BugsnagLaravel/BugsnagLaravelServiceProvider.php(61): Bugsnag_Client->__construct(NULL)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738): Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\BugsnagLaravelServiceProvider->Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('bugsnag', Array)
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('bugsnag', Array)
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsna in /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Bugsnag/Client.php on line 19
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Bugsnag Error: Invalid API key' in /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Bugsnag/Client.php:19
Stack trace:
#0 /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel/src/Bugsnag/BugsnagLaravel/BugsnagLaravelServiceProvider.php(61): Bugsnag_Client->__construct(NULL)
#1 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(738): Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\BugsnagLaravelServiceProvider->Bugsnag\BugsnagLaravel\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(674): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('bugsnag', Array)
#4 /var/app/current/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(62): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('bugsnag', Array)
#5 /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsna in /var/app/current/vendor/bugsnag/bugsnag/src/Bugsnag/Client.php on line 19
```

I ran `env` on the command line and I have an env variable called `BUGSNAG_API_KEY` and the value of it exactly matches the key at bugsnag.com for this project.

Furthermore, I have this line in my project at `./config/bugsnag.php`

`'api_key' => env('BUGSNAG_API_KEY'),`

Weirdly, I eventually tried the same command again (`php artisan migrate`) and it worked! But it's left me very unsettled as it's a production server. So I'd like to understand the problem.

Errors seem to be logging in Bugsnag as well by the way.

Comment: The Bugnsnag source throws this error when the API key is not a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try to regenerate the configuration cache with `php artisan config:cache`. It will use the current data from the .env file to generate a new configuration cache. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone...

The Bugsnag Git Repo mentions this issue:

([Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class bugsnag.logger does not exist'](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel/issues/181)

Github user `GrahamCampbell` suggested that what is actually happening is that another error exists, but it's "...trying to log to bugsnag which is causing this error, which is hiding the real error". I confirmed this was my issue by doing what user `russianryebread` suggested, which was to manually copy the `bugsnag.php` config file over to the Laravel /config directory. Once I did that now my real error shows:

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Now to troubleshoot this issue :)

Hope this helps!